# Google cloud logging LogEntry fields

Tags: python, logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am new to Google cloud logging.

I use Python [library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-logging/) and I am a little bit confused about [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogEntryOperation) fields. Are these fields meant to be manipulated by developer/code? I am trying to use "operation" field to trace operation logs with the same ID, but no matter how I try to format the log message, the operation field is still in jsonPayload.

I understood, that fields "reserved" in LogEntry would be taken to the top level of the log and rest of them would be left in jsonPayload. Am I correct?

One of many examples I have tried:

```py
log_data = {
    "operation": LogEntryOperation(id="string_id", first=True, last=False),
    "my_filed": "my field test",
    "split": {"uid": "ddsadadsad", "index": "dsadadads", "totalSplits": "2"},
}
```

or

```py
log_data = {
    "operation": {
        "id": "dsadadsadadsad",
        "producer": "dsadasdcc",
        "first": "true",
        "last": "false",
    },
    "my_filed": "my field test",
    "split": {"uid": "ddsadadsad", "index": "dsadadads", "totalSplits": "2"},
}
```

I also tried operation as a dict with the keys as it is in docs.

I use CloudLoggingHandler() added as a handler to standard Python logging. Then just:

```py
logger.info(log_data)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `operation` like below. This ensures `operation` comes as a top level field. The fields under `log_data` will always be sub fields of `jsonPayload`.

```
from google.cloud import logging
logging_client = logging.Client()
logger = logging_client.logger("struct_log")

log_data = {
"my_filed": "my field test",
"split": {"uid": "ddsadadsad", "index": "dsadadads", "totalSplits": "2"},
}

logger.log_struct(log_data, operation={"id": "string_id", "first": True, "last": False})
```